# AngularJS validate on template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validation

I want to validate my inputs from the template itself.

The span with the ng-show it not showed when the input is valid

I have to idea what am I doing wrong here:

```
<form name="registerForm" class="js-validation-register form-horizontal push-50-t push-50">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-material form-material-primary">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Please enter a username" ng-required="true">
                <label for="username">
                    <span ng-show="registerForm.username.$valid" class="text-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i></span>
                    Username
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

please your help

Comment: Can you give us some clue of what's not working or not behaving as you are expecting?

Comment: oh sorry, Just edited..

Comment: @OzBar-Shalom did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `ng-model` in your input.

**Working demo :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <form name="registerForm" class="js-validation-register form-horizontal push-50-t push-50">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-material form-material-primary">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Please enter a username" ng-model="username" ng-required="true">
                <label for="username">
                    <span ng-show="registerForm.username.$valid" class="text-success">username is valid</span>
                    Username
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add ng-modal to your input

```
<input class="form-control" ng-modal="modal" type="text" id="username" name="username"placeholder="Please enter a username" ng-required="true">
```